# Execute function in React when user stops typing

Tags: reactjs

I want to execute a function (query a search service) when use stops typing (or hits enter)
I saw some examples using lodash Debounce

I´m playing with react hooks and wanted to see if is possible to achieve this without any external libraries.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Api from './Api'

const Search = (props) => {

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState();
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

    let timeout;

    const handleSearch = (event) => {

        setKeyword(event.target.value);

        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }

        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            timeout = null;

            if (keyword) {
                callSearchService()
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    const callSearchService = () => {
        Api.search(keyword)
            .then(
                results => setResults(results),
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }

    return (
        <input type="search" onKeyUp={(e) => handleSearch(e)} />
    )

}
```

the execution is being delayed by 1000ms but then the function is called one time per character (except for the last character. that´s not being executed, I tried using onChange instead of onKeyUp, but same issue). i probably put the timeout in the wrong place. thanks for your infinite wisdom

Comment: I wonder if your timeout variable is getting wiped out because updating the state through a hook causes a control re-render and would set that timeout variable to undefined again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely! You can implement your own debounce functionality using `useEffect` and `useState`. In this example, the `value` is your user input and the code inside the `setTimeout` callback will only execute when `value` hasn't changed after 1 second.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
  const callSearchService = () => {
    Api.search(value)
      .then(
        results => setResults(results),
        error => console.log(error)
      )
  }

  let debouncer = setTimeout(() => {
    callSearchService();
  }, 1000);
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(debouncer);
  }
}, [value]);
```

What's really important here is the "cleanup" function that clears the timeout if `value` changes. If 1 second actually passes without any `value` changes, the code inside your `setTimeout` callback function will actually execute.

Comment: nice Nick. thank you! one thing i noticed is that it will execute when component is mounted. I solved with if (value != '') { // call service } but the function is still being executed. side queston I never fully understood the [value] as the second parameter of the useEffect, I should add all the variables I want to listen to there? thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's your dependency array. The effect will run whenever one of those changes.

Comment: I´m getting:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'callSearchService' I tried adding it to the dependency array but that throws another warning :(

Comment: I recommend defining the `callSearchService` variable within the `useEffect` hook, otherwise you'll either hit the missing dependency error _or_ an infinite loop. I'll update my answer.

Comment: got it thanks again! fortunately I´m not using that call anywhere else. the useEffect() is getting big!